# Inserting two foreign keys to a pivot table after form submission using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a resource provider database web app with a Resource, Location, ResourceLocation (pivot table), and ContactPerson models set up. I'm pretty sure I have the Model relationships set up correctly because from my Create A New Resource form it inserts the data into the database, it just doesn't show up in my view because the foreign keys (Resource_ID & Location_ID) aren't inserted into the pivot table. Here's the code I have so far.

**Models**

```html
class Location extends Model
{
  public function resource()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Resource', 'ResourceLocation');
    }
}

class Resource extends Model
{
  public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Location', 'ResourceLocation');
    }
}

class ResourceLocation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ResourceLocation';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'Location_ID',
        'Resource_ID'
    ];  
}
```

**Resource Controller**

```html
public function newResource(CreateNewResourceRequest $req)
{
    $resource = Resource::create(Request::only(
   'Name',
   'Description',
   'Misc_Info'
    ));

    $location = Location::create(Request::only(
   'Address',
   'Address2',
   'City',
   'Zip_Code',
   'County',
   'Hours',
   'Appt_Necessary'
    ));
 $resource->save();
  
 $resource->location()->attach($location);

    \Session::flash('flash_message', 'Resource Created Successfully!');

    return redirect('resource');
}
```

Once I hit the submit button on my form I get the error:

`BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::location()`

All the input from my form gets inserted into my database tables, but the ResourceLocation (pivot table) is left empty.

If I do `$resource->$location()->attach($location['Location_ID']);` it gives me a `Method must be a string` error. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, in my Resource Controller I have a location method:

```html
public function location()
{
    $locations = Location::all
    return view (compact('locations'));
}
```

I changed my `newResource` method to:

```html
public function newResource(CreateNewResourceRequest $req)
{ 
  ...

  $resource->save();
  $resource->locations()->attach($locations);
}
```